# How do I tighten this appliance's valve?

Tags: plumbing, valve

I am trying to tighten a washing machine and kitchen tap [valve](https://www.baur.de/p/kirchhoff-3-wege-ventil-geraeteanschluss-zusatzventil-mit-rueckflussverhinderer/AKLBB1212652964?sku=1266245858-0-1212652964#sku=1266245858-0-1212652964) to an angle valve. However, I noticed that the nut that I am tightening seems to be sitting tight while the valve is still moving along the axis. What am I doing wrong? More tightening doesn't solve the problem of the valve moving and water leaking of course when I open the angle valve.

Place of residence is in Germany.

[image: photo of valve joining at an angle]

Comment: You are stripping the threads.  All threaded attachments/nuts must go on straight, not at an angle.  Remove it and check the threads, they might be(probably) damaged and pieces need to replaced.  If very lucky and no damage to the threads, make sure everything is in a straight line(like to right edge) and try again.

Comment: Check and verify it needs a washer, you may be missing that.

Comment: @Gil washer or olive, if it's a compression fitting.

Comment: I don't like the apparent angle where the fitting on the left enters the problem joint.  That might be why you got it cross-threaded in the first place

Comment: pretty cool how it's leaking water just above the electrical socket.

Comment: @SQB: I'm not an electrician, but AFAIK there is not a prescribed minimum distance for appliance water vs. electic socket for appliance installation (unless bathroom zones apply) over here. Instead, an RCD is required. Which does not mean that I'd like this installation... Since OP will likely need to replace the angle valve as well due to destroyed thread, they may be able to at least arrange the water side pointing away from the electric socket.

Comment: @ChrisH: for this type of angle valve - appliance valve connection, I'd expect a flat washer as sealing. Further on towards the tap, I'd expect a compression fitting.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX you could well be right - you're closer to the OP than me.  Here in the UK, flat washers are often used on hose connections, but compression fittings are much more common on joints in rigid pipework, including valves.  Anyway there should be something, and neither will work with the fitting cross-threaded

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That appears to be **[cross-threaded.](https://pedalchile.com/blog/cross-threading)** *i.e.* the threads on the male and female parts are not correctly engaged with each other. The parts should be straight to each other, not off at an angle like that.

[image: cross threaded connection]

Depending how badly it's mangled, it might need to be replaced. At minimum it needs to be removed and started correctly (which may be difficult if the damage from cross-threading is severe.) Sometimes you can salvage the threads with a triangular file following the true thread path.

You can usually avoid this by making sure the parts thread together most of the way easily by hand. If you need a wrench before you have gotten very far, that's a sign that you might not be starting the threads together correctly. You should only need a wrench for final tightening.

Comment: Definitely cross threaded. Depending on what that shiny chrome piece with the red thing on it is and how much it cost, you might be able to repair the threads with a die. Odds are good that the nut will be much more cost/time efficient to simply replace unless it's captive on the bit on the left.

Comment: Use open end wrenches, not pliers or Channellocks, might be too late in this case.

Comment: I avoid cross threading by initially turning the male part in a __counter clock-wise__ direction until I feel a slight bump...which means the threads are lined up and __then__ I turn it clockwise.  (And of course the male and female parts have to be aligned).

Comment: @SteveWellens: agreed.  This has even gotten me teased with the *lefty loosy, righty tighty* slogan.  But then I explained I was ensuring proper thread alignment, said ridicule was rescinded.